# Updating a Property in ObservableCollection, Updates that property for all the records

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF ListView with ItemsSource binding to an ObservableCollection.
I've set one of the properties in MyClass to raise event when changed. In my code I add records to the observableCollection one at the time and I need to update the status of the current record while the previous records shouldn't change. When I update the status, I see that status of all the records in the ObservableCollection getting updated.
The ScanStatus is coming from a different thread that's why I'm using DispatchHelper

XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ScanResultDataCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomHeaderStyle}">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Position" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Array Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ArrayName}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Probe Array Type" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProbeArrayType}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Barcode ID" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Barcode}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="User" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Date Time" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTime}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Scan Status" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ScanStatus}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Data File" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DataFile}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
public ScanResultDisplayViewModel()
{
    DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    _resultData = new ObservableCollection<ScanResultData>();
    Messenger.Default.Register<ScanResultData>(this, CreateOrUpdateScanResultData);
}

private readonly ObservableCollection<ScanResultData> _resultData;

private ObservableCollection<ScanResultData> _scanResultDataCollection;
public ObservableCollection<ScanResultData> ScanResultDataCollection
{        
    get
    {
        return _scanResultDataCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _scanResultDataCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private ScanResultData _selectedScanResult;
public ScanResultData SelectedScanResult
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedScanResult;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedScanResult = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void CreateOrUpdateScanResultData(ScanResultData scanResultData)
{
    if (scanResultData.IsNewRecord)
        CreateScanResultData(scanResultData);
    else
        UpdateScanResultData(scanResultData);
}

private void CreateScanResultData(ScanResultData scanResultData)
{
    try
    {
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
        {
            _resultData.Add(scanResultData);
        });

        ScanResultDataCollection = _resultData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void UpdateScanResultData(ScanResultData scanResultData)
{

    try
    {
        if (ScanResultDataCollection == null)
            return;

        var currentRun = ScanResultDataCollection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Position == scanResultData.Position);
        if (currentRun != null)
            currentRun.ScanStatus = scanResultData.ScanStatus;

        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ScanResultDataCollection);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Model

```
public class ScanResultData : ObservableObject
{
    public bool IsNewRecord { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public string ArrayName { get; set; }

    public string ProbeArrayType { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string DateTime { get; set; }

    private string _scanStatus;
    public string ScanStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _scanStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _scanStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string DataFile { get; set; }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: That sure looks ok. Are you sure you don't have a foreach updating everybody at once somewhere?

Comment: Replace this line currentRun.ScanStatus = scanResultData.ScanStatus; with currentRun.ScanStatus = DateTime.Now.ToString(); and see.

Comment: I need to use the value coming from scanResult.ScanStatus and it's basically a progress that is coming from the scanner and not a DateTime value. I'm not not using any foreach statement for updating status.